# Removing adjacent and equal elements in a collection

Tags: collections, clojure, transformation

Say that I have a function:

```
(defn get-token [char]

  (defn char->number? []
    (re-matches #"\d" (str char)))

  (defn whitespace? []
    (or
      (= \space char)
      (= \newline char)))

  (defn valid-ident-char? []
    (re-matches #"[a-zA-Z_$]" (str char)))

  (cond
    (whitespace?)
    nil

    (= \' char)
    :quote

    (= \) char)
    :rparen

    (= \( char)
    :lparen

    (char->number?)
    :integer

    (valid-ident-char?)
    :identifier

    :else
    (throw (Exception. "invalid character"))))
```

When I run this function on, for instance, the string `"(test 1 2)"`, I get a list of symbols for each character:

```
'(:lparen :identifier :identifier :identifier nil :integer nil :integer :rparen)
```

Seeing that this is not entirely what I want, I am trying to write a function that takes a collection and "condenses" the collection to **combine adjacent elements that are equal**.

A final example might do this:

```
(defn combine-adjacent [coll]
  implementation...)

(->>
  "(test 1 2)"
  (map get-token)
  (combine-adjacent)
  (remove nil?))

; => (:lparen :identifier :integer :integer :rparen)
```

What is the idiomatic Clojure way to achieve this?

Comment: @soulcheck I've given it a good amount of thinking, but I haven't found any solution yet. I figure that the answer is likely a predicate function to `filter`, but as far as I know an argument to a predicate can't have knowledge about the collection that it's in. It's all very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how idiomatic it is but one way to do it would be to use `partition-by` to group elements of the incoming sequence into lists containing subsequences of the same element and then use `map` to get the first element from each of those lists.

So, in code

```
(defn combine-adjacent [input] 
     (->> input (partition-by identity) (map first)))
```

or

```
(defn combine-adjacent [input] 
    (->> (partition-by identity input) (map first))
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

Clojure 1.7 will introduce a new function called `dedupe` to accomplish exactly this:

```
(dedupe [0 1 1 2 2 3 1 2 3])
;= (0 1 2 3 1 2 3)
```

If you're prepared to use 1.7.0-alpha2, you could use it today.

The implementation relies on transducers (`dedupe` produces a transducer when called with no arguments; the unary overload is defined simply as `(sequence (dedupe) coll)`), so it wouldn't be straightforward to backport.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tricks for comparing items to the one next door:

first, we can compare it to its tail:

```
(defn combine-adjacent
  [s]
  (mapcat #(when (not= % %2) [%]) (rest s) s))
```

alternatively, we can take the sequence by twos, and drop repeats

```
(defn combine-adjacent
  [s]
  (mapcat (fn [[a b]] (if (not= a b) [a]) ())
          (partition 2 1[0 1 2 2 2 3 2 3])))
```

both of these take advantage of the helpful property of `concat` when combined with `map` that you can return zero or more elements for the result sequence for each input. The empty list for the false case in the second version is not needed, but may help with clarity.